# What is casting for JAVA8?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Can someone please explain why `TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;` work? (JAVA 8)

[TextMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) inherits [Message](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/jms/Message.html)

Message is not an instance of [Clonable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

```java
if(message instanceof TextMessage) {
   TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message; 
   String body = textMessage.getBody(); 
}
```

The expected outputs are good.

Comment: Please edit to make clear exactly what your question is. It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Got it. Better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because you are casting the message object when you set textMessage to equal it. Effectively you're telling Java to ignore what it thinks message is and instead treat it as a TextMessage object. This means it will pass the compiler stage.

In your code you've done due dilligence to check that message really is a TextMessage beforehand. If you hadn't of done that if at any point your code ran where message was not a TextMessage you would get a Java class cast exception.